# I'm trying to src a js file containing XMHTTPRequest script into my HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

If I embed my XHR file into my HTML document directly, everything works fine. As soon as I src it via 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax_gallery.js">ajax_json_gallery('gallery');</script>`

Nothing works, and I get no errors. I'm assuming it's something to do with the XHR being created in a separate file to the HTML. I just don't like XHR script cluttering up my HTML, I just want to load as an external JS file.

I've moved my main 3 scripts, galleryHandle.php, XHR.js, ajax_gallery.html all to the same dir level to keep things simple. And the gallery images are in a folder called "gallery", also on the same level.

Here's my code: 
HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/gallery.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pagetop"></div>
    <div id="thumbnailbox"></div>
    <div id="pictureframe"></div>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="XHR.js">ajax_json_gallery('gallery');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
function ajax_json_gallery(folder) {
        "use strict";
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        document.getElementById("pagetop").innerHTML = "dynamic ajax json gallery";
        var thumbnailbox = document.getElementById("thumbnailbox");
        httpRequest.open("POST", "galleryHandle.php", true);
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                var pictureframe;
                pictureframe.innerHTML = "<img src='"+data.img1.src+"'>";
                thumbnailbox.innerHTML = "";
                for (var obj in data) {
                    if (data[obj].src){
                        thumbnailbox.innerHTML += '<div onclick="putinframe(\''+data[obj].src+'\')"><img src="'+data[obj].src+'"></div>';
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        httpRequest.send("folder="+folder); 
        thumbnailbox.innerHTML = "Loading...";
}
    function putinframe(src) {
        "use strict";
        var pictureframe = document.getElementById("pictureframe");
        pictureframe.innerHTML = '<img src = " '+src+' " >';
        }
```

PHP

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
//bring in folder name
$folder = $_POST["folder"];
//start componding json 
$jsonData = '{';
//compound directory path
$dir = $folder."/";
//open directory
$dirHandle = opendir($dir);
//init while looop 
$i = 0;
while ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) {
    if(!is_dir($file) && strpos($file, '.jpg')){
        $i++;
        $src = "$dir$file";
$jsonData .= '"img'.$i.'":{ "num":"'.$i.'","src":"'.$src.'", "name":"'.$file.'" },';
    }
}
closedir($dirHandle);
$jsonData = chop($jsonData, ",");
$jsonData .= '}';
echo $jsonData;
?>
```

I understand there are some redundancies in my code but it's just a tutorial I'm going through to learn the basics of JSON building with POST, XHR.

Anyway, help appreciated as always. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

FROM [**W3C**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Your_first_look_at_JavaScript#Linking_to_an_external_JavaScript_file):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js">
  alert('I am pointless as I won\'t be executed');
</script>
```

> Upon meeting this element in a page, browsers will then load the file myscript.js and execute it. **Any content inside the script element itself will be skipped when you provide a src attribute.** The [last] example will load the file myscript.js and execute the code in it but will not execute the alert inside the script element at all.

---

### Solution

Try the following in your `head` tags:

### HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="XHR.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ajax_json_gallery('gallery');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> > `<script type="text/javascript" src="XHR.js">`

You can't have src attribute and javascript both in a single tag. Separate them out. Like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="XHR.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">ajax_json_gallery('gallery');</script>
```

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. Question, is the javascript not actually loaded until hitting the closing </script> the reason why it won't load the function?

Comment: @KyleJoseph As soon as the browser detects the `src` attribute, it really just skips the content between the `script` tags. You can [**read more here**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Your_first_look_at_JavaScript#Linking_to_an_external_JavaScript_file)